# Play Framework and Angular JS

Tags: java, angularjs, playframework

I want to use Play Framework (Java) as back end and Angular JS as front end.

Which will be the best method to implement this solution.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you provide more details! The question is very abstract.
You never choose technologies and then move into development(hype-driven-development). 
You have a problem, based on that you decide the technology.
play-framework and angular are both amazing.
But they have a use case, play is not well documented, changes between versions r huge causing up gradation a pain. Angular is modularized and very productive for huge apps, with high maintainability, but again learning curve is steep for both, so if you are looking for a short deadline with a small project size, not the rite way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We have a business application developed in oracle/D2k (Forms Reports 6i). Now we want it to be on Web Based and add some additional functionality.  So after searching on Google we found that for front end development angular js is good. I have also developed some scenario on it. Same scenario I have developed in Play Framework (Java) also using play templates. So I found comfortable on play framework for back end programming and for front end angular js. But I am facing problem while integrating both platform.

Comment: Which will be the best method to integrate both the technologies so it can be simplify development/maintenance activity.

Comment: Please be specific what issues you are facing?